# I need to print output of a shell script in to separate columns

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line

I am pasting my output of the shell script

```
for i in `cat disk.txt`; do
    echo Server:$i
    ssh -q -i ~/production_private_key.pem $i "df -h --output=source,size,used,avail,pcent| grep -v tmp"
done
```

below.

[image]

I need to print the above output to different columns like as below.

```
Server IP |  File System | Total Size | Used Space | Available Space | Percentage
```

Can someone help here?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), it is often difficult to read, and and obstacle for contributors trying to help - in particular when serving as sample input, where contributors would need to type-copy the output for testing their suggested solutions. Also, please show us what you already tried and where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the IP for each line using `xargs`:

```
echo 'Server IP |  File System | Total Size | Used Space | Available Space | Percentage'
for i in ...; do
    ssh -q -i ~/production_private_key.pem $i "df -h --output=source,size,used,avail,pcent \
    | tail -n+2 \
    | grep -v tmp" \
    | xargs -I{} printf '%s %s\n' "$i" {}
done
```

Replacing blank with `|` should be easy

Comment: Added some modification with above script and it's worked. Thanks

Comment: This is my script

output1=/tmp/disk-usage.out
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Server            Filesystem     Size Used Avail Use% "
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
for server in `more /home/ec2-user/disk.txt`
do
output=`ssh -q -i ~/production_private_key.pem $server "df -h --output=source,size,used,avail,pcent | grep -v tmp | tail -n +2"`
echo "$server $output" >> $output1
done
cat $output1 | column -t